# Pass array of data from js to cpp using WASM and Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, typescript, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to send a vector<class> from js to cpp using WASM and Emscripten. I've written the cpp and bindings code, but I'm not sure how to write the js side of code.

```
class A
{
public: 
    int x;
    int y;
    A(int xVal, int yVal): 
    x(xVal), y(yVal) 
    {}
};

typedef std::vector<A> AVector;
```

```
namespace util
{
    class Print
    {
        // Loops in vector and prints the x and y values
        static void print(AVector aObjs);
    }
}
```

The bindings code is

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(A)
{
    class_<A>("A")
    .constructor<int, int>()
    ;
    
    register_vector<A>("AVector");
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Print)
{
    class_<Print>("Print")
    .class_function("print", &util::Print::print)
    ;
    
    register_vector<A>("vector<A>");
}
```

I'm trying to write the js side of code like:

```
declare class A {
    constructor(
        xPos: number,
        yPos: number
    );
}

declare class Print {
    static print(aVec: A[])
}

interface MyModule extends EmscriptenModule
{
    AVector: A[];
}

// js func
public test(module: MyModule)
{
    const aVec = new module.AVector()      // Getting error that it has no construct signatures
    const aVec = Array<A>();               // The print function is also updated in js
    aVec.push(new A(5, 1));
    Print.print(aVec);                     // Error - Cannot pass "[object Object]" as a AVector
}
```

I'm not sure how should I write the code on JS Side to create a vector and pass the same in cpp. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: wow that's tricky! the `std::vector` from c++ does not translate to a js array directly.